# Android 12 splash windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon custom icon size

Tags: android, themes, splash-screen, android-12

I want to set a custom icon to splash screen using the following code?
what size should my splash_logo be?

```
  <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_logo</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">2000</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

Comment: 24 X 24 worked fine for me.